# How to return the view result of another action in the same asp.net core mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to show the result of the `Show` method below from `ShowById` but I get `InvalidOperationException: The view 'ShowById' was not found`

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ShowById(int id) 
    {
        Expression<Func<Question, bool>> findById = (q) => q.QuestionId == id;
        return await this.Show(findById);
    }

    private async Task<IActionResult> Show(
        Expression<Func<Question, bool>> predExp) 
    {
        var question = await _context.Questions
            .Where(predExp)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (question == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }

        question.Topics = await (
            from topic in _context.Topics
            join qtopic in _context.QuestionTopics on topic.TopicId equals qtopic.TopicId 
            where qtopic.QuestionId == question.QuestionId 
            select topic
            ).ToListAsync();

        question.Answers = await _context.Answers
            .Where(a => a.QuestionId == question.QuestionId)
            .ToListAsync();

        return View(question);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the name of the view explicitly. So the last line would be:

```
return View(nameof(Show), question);
```